# Folder in Folder Content Types

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-type, folder

I am trying to  add a folder content type for a document library / list , but I can't find Folder !!

I go to : library settings , content types , add from content types , select folder content type, I got only summery task option !!!

Maybe i missing something , can someone help me !

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own Content Type (MyFolder) which inherits from folder. Add your newly created MyFolder to your library, and you're good to go.

[image]